# Video on mobiles

Tags: html, azure, html5-canvas, html5-video, mime-types

Even thought i have my vidoes in in mp4 webm and ogg
it wont play on and ipad or iphone

and my web.config has all the right mime types

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg"/>
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm"/>
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<video width="720" height="480" autoplay>
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="test.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="test.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

hosting on windows azure, any ideas what this is not working ? i just can not figure it out.

Comment: You posted your web.config twice instead of your html page.

Comment: oops my bad updated, someone has said autoplay does not work well with moblie devices, but other then that I am not sure.